# jQuery Table Live Edit

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a table that can modify it's content via jquery by clicking it, appearing the input box, and if it's out of focus, it will go back again into a text (I did it inside a span element)

```
$arr = array("fname", "lname", "company", "jobtitle", "category", "email", "phonenumber", "mobilenumber", "remarks");
            foreach ($arr as &$value) {
                    echo "
                    $('.$value').click(function() {
                        $(this).replaceWith(function() {
                                return \"<span class='{$value}3'><input class='{$value}2' style = 'width:100%' name= '$value' value=\"+ \"'\"+$(this).text() + \"'\"+ \"/></span>\";        
                        });
                    });
                    ";

                    echo "
                        $('.{$value}2').blur(function() {
                            $('.{$value}3').replaceWith(function() {
                                    return \"<span class='$value'>$value</span>\";
                            });
                        });
                    ";
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the line that what you have there. It drives me.

```
return \"<span class='{$value}3'><input class='{$value}2' style = 'width:100%' name= '$value' value='\"+ $(this).text() + \"' /></span>\";
```